# Problems when running app on smaller creen size iphone

Tags: iphone, image, resize

I am building an app using Xcode 5 and used images for retina iPhone 5 as well launch images both in 640x960 and 640x1136.
When I run the app on iPhone 5 everything works grew.
When I run it on iPhone 4/4s some of my buttons are lost seems like the app is over sized.
What am i doing wrong?

Buttons created programmatically and code is here:

```
self.questionLabel.text = self.question;
[self.imageView setImage:self.image];

UIImage *normal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question_button.png"];
UIImage *selected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question_button_selected.png"];

self.btnOne = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.btnOne.tag = 1;
[self.btnOne.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
[self.btnOne setBackgroundImage:normal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnOne setBackgroundImage:selected forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

self.btnTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.btnTwo.tag = 2;
[self.btnTwo.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
[self.btnTwo setBackgroundImage:normal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnTwo setBackgroundImage:selected forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

self.btnThree = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.btnThree.tag = 3;
[self.btnThree.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
[self.btnThree setBackgroundImage:normal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnThree setBackgroundImage:selected forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

self.btnFour = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.btnFour.tag = 4;
[self.btnFour.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
[self.btnFour setBackgroundImage:normal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnFour setBackgroundImage:selected forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

//Assign the frames
_btnOne.frame = [((NSValue *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:0]) CGRectValue];
_btnTwo.frame = [((NSValue *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:1]) CGRectValue];
_btnThree.frame = [((NSValue *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:2]) CGRectValue];
_btnFour.frame = [((NSValue *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:3]) CGRectValue];
```

Comment: Hope you are not talking about putting buttons on Launch Image. Now if your button is getting off screens in your views & viewControllers then you need to share some code on how you are creating the button. 

You must use relative frame & bounds rather than just giving hardcoded values for the frame of button. Also detect the device & then render the content that can be affected by screen size.

Comment: just updated my post with the buttons created programmatically

Comment: so what is there in the `indexArray` ? The `CGRectValue` ??

Comment: yes i have searched all over and it seems i can't find the answer...the worst case scenario is to submit the app just for 4 inch screens

Comment: The buttons that you have created via code is the main reason. Can you show what are the content of your `indexArray` ? You need to tell what values you have in each index for `CGRectValue`.